# Show action in polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic resource Discussion that can belong to either the Project, Task, or Subtask.

At one point I wish to reroute to show action of discussions controller. To do that, I need discussion id (which I get from params) and I need to know what the parent is (which I get from params also).

So, to route to show action, I'd have to have 3 cases:

```
  project_discusison_path(@project, @discussion)
  task_discussion_path(@task, @discussion)
  subtask_discussion_path(@subtask, @discussion)
```

How to write this 3 cases in one path helper? (looking something like below)

```
parent_discussion_path(@parent, @discussion)
```

Remember, I can find and have all the variables. Only writing the path is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're generating a link in a--for instance--`link_to`, you can use this array syntax:

```
link_to "Show Discussion", [@parent, @discussion]
```

Under the hood, this achieves the same thing as the `polymorphic_path` and `polymorphic_url` methods:

```
polymorphic_url([@parent, @discussion])
```